# Admob Ads within Textview

Tags: android, admob

I have a textview created programmatically, loading some data using settext().After the end of first paragraph and before the start of second paragraph I need to load a banner ads using Admob to show up. At the end settext should be called which set all data with Ads.I have tried a lot but not able to understand how to do it.Please help me..

Answer (score 2):

You can't place the admob ad inside TextView. Create two textViews for two paragraphs and place the admob banner between the two textviews. This is a better approach

Comment: Thanx A.J.It really helped me.I have wasted lots of time today to research on this.